# Liquibase start script from another script

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I have two scripts, one creates table, one fills it in, they look like this.

```
    databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: "0"
      author: author
      changes:
        - createTable:
            columns:
              - column:
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                    primaryKey: true
                    primaryKeyName: board_id
                  name: id
                  type: integer
              - column:
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
                  name: engines
                  type: varchar(45)
//more code



    databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: board_table_fill
      author: 777
      changes:
        - insert:
            tableName: boards
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: id
                  value: 777
              - column:
                  name: engines
                  value: stock
              - column:
                  name: markets
                  value: index
//more code
```

I need to start both scripts, how do I do that? That's application properties:

```
    spring:
  application:
    name: 777
  datasource:
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: 777
    password: 777
    url: 777
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: validate
  liquibase:
    change-log: "classpath:db/changelog/db.changelog-777.yml"
```

In my case only the script to create the table starts, but I need both. I'm new to liquibase, sorry for a stupid question.

Comment: You need to create a master changelog that includes the other two. See here: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/include.html
The example is in XML but the YAML version is straightforward. Here is an example: https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/blob/master/spring-boot/data-migration/liquibase/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by CT Liv in comments:

You need to create a master changelog that includes the other two.

See here: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/include.html

The example is in XML but the YAML version is straightforward.
Here is an example: https://github.com/thombergs/code-examples/blob/master/spring-boot/data-migration/liquibase/src/main/resources/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml